# Cannot read linked data from DB

Tags: c#, .net, aspnetboilerplate

I have configured this two entities:

**Host.cs**

```
public class Host : FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<HostLine> HostLines { get; set; }
}
```

**HostLine.cs**

```
public class HostLine: FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Host Host { get; set; }
}
```

Manually, I inserted in the DB one tuple for `Host` and `HostLine`, linking them accordingly.

```
select Id, Name from [MyDB].dbo.Hosts;

Id | Name
-----------
1  | Host1

select Name, HostId from [MyDB].dbo.HostLines;

HostId | Name
------------------
1      | HostLine1
```

The `HostLine`'s FK to the `Host` table is configured as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

Then, I implemented a simple Service which extends `AsyncCrudAppService` to provide CRUD operation on both the `Host` and `HostLine` entities.

```
public class HostsAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Host, HostDto, int, PagedResultRequestDto, CreateHostDto, HostDto>, IHostsAppService
{

    public HostsAppService(IRepository<Host> repository)
       : base(repository)
    {
    }

    protected override HostDto MapToEntityDto(Host entity)
    {
        return base.MapToEntityDto(entity);
    }

}
```

I added the override to the method `MapToEntityDto` in order to see the data read from the DB (it will be removed).
When I call the Get REST method of the service via the Angular client I can reach the `MapToEntityDto()` method, but the `Host` entity does not have a value for the `HostLines` `List` field.
So it seems that the `Host` repository is not reading the linked data from the `HostLine` table.

Am I lacking some kind of configuration to let the `Host` repository read also the `HostLine` data?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the HostLines manually with the below code.

```cs
public class TaskAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Host, HostDto, int, PagedResultRequestDto, CreateHostDto, HostDto>, IHostsAppService
{

//...
    protected override IQueryable<Task> CreateFilteredQuery(GetAllTasksInput input)
    {
        return base.CreateFilteredQuery(input).Include(x=>x.HostLines);
    }

//...

}
```

Further information see https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Application-Services#crud-permissions

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you

Comment: this is the query while retrieving data from DB so you can add filters, group by and sort the query in this `CreateFilteredQuery` method.